# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int' pygame

Tags: python, typeerror

when i try running my code i get the TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int' error for opponent.center. This is pygame btw.

```
if opponent.center < ball.y:
    opponent.top += opponent_speed
if opponent.center > ball.y:
    opponent.bottom -= opponent_spee
```

but if i do opponent.top it works just fine is there a reason for this.

Comment: Evidently `center` is a tuple, not a number. Presumably you mean one component of it: `center[1]` perhaps?

Comment: This error means that one of values is tuple, for example you can't do that :`40 > (60, 53)`. Be sure that `opponent.center` and `ball.y` is `int` or `float`. Be sure that output doesn't have `()`.

Comment: `center` represents a point in the plane, and thus has two coordinates. `top`, on the other hand, is the topmost y-coordinate, which is a number.

Answer (score 0):

> but if i do opponent.top it works just fine is there a reason for this.

Yes. `opponent.top` is the Y coordinate of the top edge of the `opponent` rectangle. You can compare that against the Y coordinate of the `ball` position.

`opponent.center` is the center **position** of the `opponent` rectangle. **You can't compare a position (tuple) against a number.** Hence why you're getting this error.

Suggested fix: Use `opponent.center[1]` instead of `opponent.center` as you seemingly are trying to compare Y coordinates.

Note: `ball.y` is the same as `ball.top`.

Comment: I think you mean "instead of `opponent.center`"